# Log file not updated after manually writing into it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, amazon-ec2, puma, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Rails application running under Puma which is configured to log to a file called `puma.stdout.log`. I also have a Amazon Cloudwatch Logs agent that is monitoring this file so that I can access these logs for all my EC2 instances in the AWS Cloudwatch console.

When I write manually to this log file, it stops getting updated. When I open the log file, the last line is the line I added even though more logs should appear. Timestamps and file size don't change either.

The weird thing is: Cloudwatch is still getting updated with new logs from the agent monitoring this particular log file and the application runs just fine, so Puma keeps logging to this file but I can't see the changes.

When I restart Puma, I can see new logs into this log file and everything is back to normal.

Why can't I see this log file updated after writing manually to it?

Comment: maybe permission issue? ie puma process owner is different from yours?

Comment: Or maybe the text editor you use locks the file.

Comment: Ok the problem was related to vim `.swp` files management. If I just echo traces into the log file, everything is fine. Thanks!